# Backup a Hyper-V cluster

Tags: backup, hyper-v

We need a backup application to backup our Hyper-V cluster VMs on a shared Dell SAN to another server with 20TB of disk space.

Any ideas of software that works well?

We tried using DPM 2010 installed on a Dell R510 but DPM will not see the local D drive which is reserved for just DPM to use.

Comment: DPM requires an "unprovisioned" drive (i.e. not formatted, no partitions).

Comment: Yeah we know. We set that up and still it fails to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DPM works fine for Hyper-V.....If you have already created a logical drive you probably need to delete it.  DPM does its own volume management so in needs a blank volume to work from.

Comment: Yes we tried that. Left the drive as offline - does not work, left the drive as not initialised - does not work, left the drive online with no partition - does not work. ahhhh.  Would love to use DPM but it will not see the space.

Comment: So drive definitely needs to be online but it should be unallocated.  When you have on online unallocated disk and you go to add the disk do you see anything?

Comment: no nothing. We did a re-scan then clicked Add and there is no disks in the box to add to the storage group.

Comment: Hmmm have you tried talking to MSFT?  Because this should be working.  I am rooting for DPM because I have seen how well it works in my organization.....

Comment: I'm going to try completely removing it and re-installing it from fresh. Does it really work that well?

Comment: DPM is a really nice product and probably your best bet for this job.